# Objective and Constraint rules for SubModels in PAO

Tags: pyomo

My question refers to the PAO package, I hope this is the right place to ask.

I am wondering whether it is possible to create lower-level objectives or constraints in a bilevel pao model using "rule"-functions.

I would like to create a lower-level objective and tried the following:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po
from pao.pyomo import *


M = pe.ConcreteModel()
M.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)
M.x = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

M.L = SubModel(fixed=M.x)
M.L.y = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))


def ul_obj_rule(M):
    """upper-level objective"""
    return(sum(M.x[i] + M.L.y[i] for i in M.S))

M.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ul_obj_rule, sense=pe.minimize)

def ll_obj_rule(M):
    return(sum(M.L.y[i] for i in M.S))

M.L.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ll_obj_rule, sense=pe.maximize)
```

This resulted in an error:
`AttributeError: 'SubModel' object has no attribute 'S'`

I tried adding a Set identical to M.S to the SubModel:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po
from pao.pyomo import *


M = pe.ConcreteModel()
M.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)
M.x = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

M.L = SubModel(fixed=M.x)
M.L.y = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))
M.L.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)


def ul_obj_rule(M):
    """upper-level objective"""
    return(sum(M.x[i] + M.L.y[i] for i in M.S))

M.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ul_obj_rule, sense=pe.minimize)

def ll_obj_rule(M):
    return(sum(M.L.y[i] for i in M.S))

M.L.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ll_obj_rule, sense=pe.maximize)
```

which resulted in:
`AttributeError: 'SubModel' object has no attribute 'L'`

Creating the same objective but using "expr" instead of "rule" works fine:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po
from pao.pyomo import *


M = pe.ConcreteModel()
M.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)
M.x = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

M.L = SubModel(fixed=M.x)
M.L.y = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

M.obj = pe.Objective(expr=sum(M.x[i] + M.L.y[i] for i in M.S), sense=pe.minimize)

M.L.obj = pe.Objective(expr=sum(M.L.y[i] for i in M.S), sense=pe.maximize)
```

I encountered the same problem when I tried to initialize constraints. Does anyone know if and how I could set up objective or constraint rules for bilevel models in PAO without encountering the described problems?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: solved it using M.model(). This script works:

```
import pyomo.environ as pe
import pyomo.opt as po
from pao.pyomo import *


M = pe.ConcreteModel()
M.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)
M.x = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

M.L = SubModel(fixed=M.x)
M.L.y = pe.Var(M.S, bounds=(0, None))

def ul_obj_rule(M):
    """upper-level objective"""
    mo = M.model()
    return(sum(mo.x[i] + mo.L.y[i] for i in M.S))

M.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ul_obj_rule, sense=pe.minimize)

def ll_obj_rule(M):
    mo = M.model()
    return(sum(mo.L.y[i] for i in mo.S))

M.L.obj = pe.Objective(rule=ll_obj_rule, sense=pe.maximize)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the 'argument' passed into the function ll_obj_rule when it is called in the last line is M.L (instead of the M that you are expecting.) {And M.L (The submodel) does not have an attribute L.}

A simple fix would be omitting the L in the ll_obj_rule:

```
def ll_obj_rule(M):
    return(sum(M.y[i] for i in M.S))
```

On an unrelated note, I have been trying to run pao on google colab unsuccessfully, often encountering this error.  "ImportError: cannot import name 'SimpleBlock' from 'pyomo.core'." Have you encountered this error before? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thank you! I needed to duplicate the RangeSet to the SubModel by adding the code line `M.L.S = pe.RangeSet(1, 10)`, but now it works. Still, how could I address upper-level variables in a lower-level constraint if M.L is passed?
I didn't encounter the error message you described yet.

Comment: That is an excellent question. I suspect this may have been an oversight during development.

I'm interested to know what dependencies you were using to run pao successfully. 

Mine are: 
(pao version: 1.0.1)
(scipy version:  1.4.1)
(pyomo version: 6.0.1)
(munch version: 2.5.0)
(parameterized version: 0.8.1)

Comment: I am using the following versions for the dependencies that you listed: pao - 1.0.1, scipy - 1.6.0, pyomo - 5.7.3, munch - 2.5.0, parametrized is not installed.

Comment: I finally solved this problem using the M.model() functionality i came across.